# What maps have multiple organ droppers?

Tags: path-of-exile

For Metamorph, I'd like to maximize my chances of getting unique organs (eyes particularly). Are there any particular maps I can run that offer multiple unique organ drops?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but don't forget that you can also roll the twinned modifier (doubles number of bosses) to have an even greater selection of organs to farm those eye/liver drops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer on Reddit:
[image]

A comment on the thread pointed out Tower is only 1 enemy.

Source: [Wanna do more Metamorphs and are missing some eyes?](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/ehnfmb/wanna_do_more_metamorphs_and_are_missing_some/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several maps that have multiple bosses. Couldn't find any lists, so this is mostly from memory. Some maps might be incorrect or missing.

Canyon - 2

City Square - 3

Colonnade - 2

Courthouse - 3

Courtyard - 3

Coves - 2

Crystal Ore - 3

Dig - 2

Excavation - 2

Graveyard - 3

Precinct - 4-6?

Racecourse - 3

Strand - 2

Vaal Pyramid - 3